# Axiom 4 in epistemic logic

Tags: logic, epistemology, knowledge, modal-logic

In epistemic logic, axiom 4 says that if I know *p*, then I know that I know *p*. What is the philosophical value of such an axiom?

Comment: See [Epistemological Principles in Epistemic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/#EpisPrinEpisLogi); it is a quite obvious principle: "**Kφ → KKφ**   states that what is known is known to be known." But we may use logic where this principle is not valid: logic related to frames where the relation **R** on worlds is not *transitive*.

Comment: This is called the KK thesis, and it reflects the old Cartesian idea of "luminosity of knowledge" - while one can be uncertain about external things they are supposed to have unlimited access to their own mind, and hence cannot know unknowingly, see [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/kk-princ/#H4). The thesis is also linked to not having knowledge by luck, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/formal-epistemology/#SelKno), and standing ready to justify what is known, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KK_thesis). Any of those motivations give strong grounds for rejecting KK.

Comment: It's a tautology and tautologues are useful as they are always true. There's an alternative which goes Pa => PPa. That is, if I can prove a, then I can prove that I can prove a. Technically, this is useful in that you can prove Godel's theorems on incompleteness. If you want details you should ask on Math Overflow.